# Opening a Local PDF file in Browser using JSP

Tags: html, jsp, file-io

I have tried to open a PDF file from the local disk.

For example the Location is:

```
E:/files/IT/cat1/cat1Notification.pdf
```

But during runtime the link changes to:

```
http://localhost:8080/Office_Automation/E:/files/IT/cat1/cat1Notification.pdf
```

How to do i get rid of `http://localhost:8080/Office_Automation/` from the link and open the file?

I have used

```
<a href="<%=path%>">click here</a>
```

Comment: use iframe `<iframe height="300" width="600" src="/res/abc.pdf">` may solve the issue!

Comment: It doesn't Solve anyways thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the local file you need to use the [file scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) in your URL

As you path is a [Windows path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Windows) `E:/files/IT/cat1/cat1Notification.pdf`, the link's href needs `file:///` added before the your jsp's `<%=path%>` variable, so that the browser knows it needs to open a local file on the user's machine.

So your link should look like this

```
<a href="file:///<%=path%>">click here</a>
```

Which in your browser will resolve to `file:///E:/files/IT/cat1/cat1Notification.pdf`

Without the file scheme the browser assumes that your link is relative to the webpage and tries to resolve the link by making a request to your webapp. This is why you were getting `http://localhost:8080/Office_Automation/E:/files/IT/cat1/cat1Notification.pdf`

Comment: What does the full path of the links href in the rendered source (view source) look like?